# SQL query that works only on number not text

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on a table in Teradata which supports sql query.
I've got table which has marks column and values as.
Marks
80
90
fail
70
40
fail
I am trying to build a query that will give me percentage of this marks out of total 150 like 80/150*100
but I want to skip column which contains texts like "fail".
`Select CAST(marks as float)/150*100`
this gives error of text in the marks column
 How can I do it without introducing new column which contains only integer values?

Comment: Can you just rewrite the query to exclude the columns where the value is "fail"?

Comment: I suggest use a Case statement. Like 'Case when Marks > 0 THEN CAST(marks as float)/150*100 ELSE 0

Comment: A quick google search shows that teradata supports regular expressions.  That is the most reliable approach.

Comment: @DanBracuk is right. Use this for positive numbers: SELECT *
 FROM Table_Name
 WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(COL1,'^[0-9]+$','c')=1;

Comment: `Select CAST(marks as float)/150*100 from yourtable where marks not like '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: I am working on old TERADATA demo version that doesnot support REGEXP

Comment: I like the concept but it gives me zero rows. @VR46

Comment: @zohaibkhan - I checked it on `sql server` it [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11b62/1). May be teradata doesnot support some thing like this `marks not like '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: What's your Teradata release? And which possible non-numeric values exist besides *fail*?

Comment: version 6 demo. Besides 'fail' it could be any thing. @dnoeth

Comment: Version 6 is over 8 years old, it's a demo, why don't you switch to a newer release?